# can I just use a DBMS , or should I invent my own DataStructure?

Tags: database, algorithm, data-structures

Iam making a program that deal a lot with data , but Iam facing two directions, the algorithem can just query the database every time it need data , or should I create my own datastructure and feed the data just once.

I think for a big data you really don't know how does the DBMS will deal with your query?  It will may be take a while, especially if will be a lot of traffic, so it's much better to invent your own data structure , so is that right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need a k/v storage, try LevelDB (http://code.google.com/p/LevelDB).

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested only in a subset of columns, you can create a view in the DB. So that the table is not always scanned.